# Want to trigger Different methods at different time interval in Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, timer-trigger

I have hosted my web job through website (with option **Added Existing** project as a **Azure Webjob**). I am want to trigger different methods at different time interval.

Code :

```
static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.UseTimers();   
    var host = new JobHost();
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

    public static void TimerTrig1([TimerTrigger("00:00:02")] TimerInfo timer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Triggered");
    }  

    public static void TimerTrig2([TimerTrigger("00:00:04")] TimerInfo timer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Triggered");
    }
```

and webjob-publish-settings.json is :

```
        {
         "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
         "webJobName": "KentDataImporterWebJob",
         "runMode": "Continuous"
        }
```

I need a solution so that I can trigger these function on 2 Sec or 4 Sec.

So I want to trigger different methods on different interval in Azure Web Job when my azure web job hosted with different web Site.

Comment: What did you try, what didn't work an where can we help you? You've only told us what you wanted to do and pasted some code but I'm still not sure what the problem is...?

Comment: What does " not working" meaning?  Is there any detail exception info? Could you please explain more info about not working?

Comment: Not working means nothing happened not any method trigger .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. A couple of caveats:

Make sure that in the Main method of your Program class, you call the config.UseTimers() method. If you do not, your TimerTriggers will not fire. Also, make sure that your WebJob is continuous.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.UseTimers();
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Comment: I have used this option.  var host = new JobHost(config); It's not working.

I have hosted my web job through website (with option Added Existing project as a Azure Webjob). my Web Job is not a Main application , it hosted with another website so i think . it might be a issue.